# Сделать рамку для изображения

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо в рамку поместить изображение-можно любое.

Answer (score 4):

```css
.frame {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.frame > img {
  width: 500px;
}
.frame::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -5%;
  left: -5%;
  right: -5%;
  bottom: -5%;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxcd6.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylivx.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Как то так

```css
.frame
{
 background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxcd6.png);
 width:1200px;
 height:950px;
}
.inner-img
{
 position:relative;
 margin-left:70px;
 margin-top:70px;
 width:1080px;
 height:800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame"><div class="inner"><img class="inner-img" src="http://i.imgur.com/zv06qUU.jpg"></div></div>
```